# How to create Navigation bar with back button to the left?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, interface-builder, uinavigationbar

In my app I am trying to navigate from the Second ViewController to the First ViewController using a Navigation Bar Back Button, but while dragging and dropping the navigation bar onto the ViewController in my App's XIB I am just able to get the bar with title.

What am I doing wrong? I am using Xcode 4.6. and .xib files to design the view. Here's What I'm getting now:

[image: Navigation Bar Without Back Button]

Here's what I'm looking for:

[image: Navigation Bar with Back Button]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add this code in your BUS2AppDelegate.h file

```
@interface BUS2AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate>
{
     UINavigationController *navController;   //you have added this code?
}
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIWindow *window;

@property (strong, nonatomic) ViewController *viewController;
    @end
```

and in BUS2AppDelegate.m file

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
     self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];

        // Override point for customization after application launch.
    self.viewController = [[BUS2ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"BUS2ViewController" bundle:nil];

    // View Controller with each Navigational stack support.
    navController = [[UINavigationController alloc]
                     initWithRootViewController:self.viewController];
    self.window.rootViewController = navController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    return YES;
}
```

add this code in your first view controller

```
#import "AAlesund.h"

- (IBAction)secodVCBtnClicked:(id)sender {


    AAlesund *aAlesund = [[AAlesund alloc] initWithNibName:@"AAlesund" bundle:nil];

self.navigationItem.title = @"Master";
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:aAlesund  animated:NO];
}
```

To add title in navigation bar in second view controller add this code

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    UILabel *nav_title1 = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(60, 10, 220, 25)];
    nav_title1.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial-BoldMT" size:18];
    nav_title1.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    nav_title1.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = NO;
    nav_title1.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
    nav_title1.text = @"Detail";
    nav_title1.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    self.navigationItem.titleView = nav_title1;
}
```

this is the output.

[image]

Comment: Tried adding it, what now? will the navigation bar and button apear on second view?

Comment: If you get any problem then let me know

Comment: I aint getting anything. What words in the text do i need to change, might left one out.

Comment: you mean you dont see any thing in secondVC ?

Comment: Im trying to get a "back button on a navigation bar on second view" There is no "back" button there already. I added your method to the first VC, and i should expect seeing it in the second? thanks for helping me out!

Comment: check my update now ,you have to add NavigationBar in your app delegate sorry i have totally forgoten it.now i have checked that code in my project and it working great

Comment: Plotted in what seemed natural to change, but got three errors in appdelegade.m, you see the name of my first and second, could you plot it in for me? http://i.stack.imgur.com/BbnyD.png

Comment: first error is bcoz there is two method didfinishwithlonching option so delete first method which not added by us end second error is you have not added navigation controllers code in delegate.h file

Comment: I got rid of the first, but i have added the the second, see. http://i.stack.imgur.com/zAVAq.png

Comment: check now i have ploated using your VC name

Comment: dont add second appdelegate in BUS2appdelegate.h file.put navigationcontroller code in BUS2Appdlegate code.check my update for BUS2Appdelegate file.

Comment: wait one sec, im creating a fresh project with same name and plot it in.

Comment: and dont forget to add import code in BUS2ViewController.m file

Comment: if Im going to gave alot of more pages, whitch information do i need to copy?

Comment: i dont understand.you mean if you create more viewcontroller? then you have to copy that secodVCBtnClicked code to go to another view and add that nav_title1 code in every viewcontroller

Answer (score 1):

Navigation controller provides a default navigation bar and a back button.But the back button title change is a little messy thing

**PROGRAMATICALLY**

```
   UIStoryboard *astoryBoard=[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
    ViewController2 *vc=[astoryBoard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ViewController2"];
  
    
    UIBarButtonItem *newBackButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle: @"Master" style: UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target: nil action: nil];
    [[self navigationItem] setBackBarButtonItem: newBackButton];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:YES];
```

If you are using **segue** include these lines to the parent VC

```
 UIBarButtonItem *newBackButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle: @"Master" style: UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target: nil action: nil];
    [[self navigationItem] setBackBarButtonItem: newBackButton];
```

**Just for back**

Code wise

```
  UIStoryboard *astoryBoard=[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
        ViewController2 *vc=[astoryBoard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ViewController2"];
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:YES];
```

Not storyboard

create an instance of your 2nd VC and then use this code

```
YourViewController *VC=[[YourViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"yournibname" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:VC animated:YES];
```

Comment: I only need back, the picture was only to illustrate

Comment: well then you can ignore the  new button init and adding code

Comment: then create your vc instance and run the code,Updated the answer.Make sure you are using the navigation controllers rootviewcontroller in the appdelegate

Comment: I probably sound very dumb, but what do you mean by "Instance"? Im coding in my second language and this is my first time doing the back button. Thank you very much for helping me out here!

Comment: I wrote this into my firstviewcontroller.m file and changed "YourViewController" at both places, do i need to change "VC"? And how to i find my "Nibname" ?